# Scrollbar in TKinter with multiple widgets

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

So for a couple of days I worked on a little project to make a to do list app for my raspberry pi with a database and an http server. I figured out almost everything but I'm stuck on making a scrollbar for all the multiple labels + delete buttons that it creates. I know my code is REALLY messy but I'm working on it. Any help on the scroll bar is appreciated. Here is the full code:

[Link to code because it was too much](https://gist.github.com/emistery/dc9274936a187bad7a366373488af0db) Code slightly edited

Comment: This question has been asked many times. it involves a scrollbar and a canvas to get the job done. Please review other post on here for details.

Comment: @Mike-SMTCouldn't find it sadly. Normally I never ask anything here cause I can find it but now I'm completely stuck

Comment: I meant that scrollbars don't support Labels. And I need labels I guess

Comment: I think you are confused on the process. You see what you need to do is apply a frame to the canvas and then all your labels in side of that frame. Then configure that canvas to scroll with a scrollbar. This gives you the practical affect of scrolling across multiple labels.

Comment: Alright. I'm kinda confused by Tkinters root/master/frame/canvas/window etc. That's probably why my code is so messy

Comment: Please don't link to code on another site. Instead, [edit] your question to include a small [mcve].

Comment: `root` is just a variable name assigned to the default instance of tkinter. It is the main window that everything starts from. `master` is a variable usually in the argument section that is used to link back to the root or controlling class. `/frame/canvas/window` refers to the containers that hold widgets. A canvas is used mainly for drawing stuff like charting but can be used to do other useful complex things like scroll sets of widgets. A window is like the root window or a top level window (pop up window).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't exactly answer your question, but this is something I learned and I think it might be useful.

Tkinter is not super easy for larger projects and it is a pain to get the UI to set how you want. I personally am TERRIBLE with UI and always spent hours doing very minor tweaks. I personally Love Qt designer (it is free and it even comes with Anaconda). I use it for all of my UIs now. It is a graphical way to build your UI and is much more initiative and powerful.

With Qt it will create scroll bars in just a few clicks and you can customize all the aspects of it.

I was building a project and spent WEEKS with Tkinter, I build the same app, only better in about one day. It is worth starting over.